# Android: Multiple selection dialog assign name to element from array

Tags: java, android, arrays

---

I'm converting my multiple selection checkbox dialog to come from a public property & public class (so I can pull it from anywhere).

However, normally when I do something from a class I have whatever.ID availble to me, and whatever.Name, I guess just a normal multi dimensional array. However I can't work out the syntax in this situation.

Here is my custom class:

```
package com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.Globals;

public class clsNameID {
    public String Name;
    public String ID;

}
```

Heres what's creating the array:

```
public static List<clsNameID> assetHelperTypes(){
    Log.e("Asset Helper Types:", "Started");
    clsNameID AssetDetails = null;
    List<clsNameID> mHelperNames = new ArrayList<clsNameID>();
    File dbfile = new File(Global.currentDBfull); 

    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
    Cursor f = db.rawQuery("select * from assetobservationtypes", null);  
    Log.e("Asset Helper Types:", "Cursor run");

    if(f.getCount() > 0) {
        f.moveToFirst();
           while(!f.isAfterLast()) {
               AssetDetails     = new clsNameID();
               AssetDetails.ID = f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("AssetObsID"));
               AssetDetails.Name = f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("Observation"));
               mHelperNames.add(AssetDetails);
               Log.e("Found Item:", AssetDetails.Name);
                f.moveToNext();
           }
    }


    f.close();

    return mHelperNames;
}
```

Heres where I am trying to use the array:

```
public void addCondition(View view){

          List<clsNameID> mHelperNames = DBFunctions.assetHelperTypes();

            final List<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("My Title")
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(mHelperNames.toArray(new CharSequence[mHelperNames.size()]), null,
                            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                    if (isChecked) {

                                        mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {

                                        mSelectedItems.remove(Integer
                                                .valueOf(which));
                                    }   
                                }
                            })



   .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Create onlcick method
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Create onlcick method
                   }
               });
        builder.show();

}
```

I guess what I really need to be doing is something like `.setMultiChoiceItems(mHelperNames.toArray.Name(new CharSequence[mHelperNames.size()])`

But clearly that wont work. How do I assign the name value to my setMultiChoiceItems array?

Tom